# Decoding problem with fitz.Document in Python 3.7

Tags: python, pymupdf, text-decoding

I want to extract the text of a PDF document and use some regular expressions to filter for information.

I am coding in Python 3.7.4 using *fitz* for parsing the PDF document. The PDF document is written in German. My code looks as follows:

```py
doc = fitz.open(pdfpath)
pagecount = doc.pageCount
page = 0
content = ""

while (page < pagecount):
    p = doc.loadPage(page)
    page += 1
    content = content + p.getText()
```

Printing the content, I realized that the first (and important) half of the document is decoded as a strange mix of Japanese (?) signs and others, like this: `ｮ｡ｵｳｷ･ｩｴｵｮｧ＠ｭ`.

I tried to solve it with different decodings (latin-1 and iso-8859-1), but the encoding is definitely in UTF-8.

```py
content= content+p.getText().encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")
```

I also have tried to get the text using [minecart](https://pypi.org/project/minecart/):

```py
import minecart

file = open(pdfpath, 'rb')

document = minecart.Document(file)

for page in document.iter_pages():
    for lettering in page.letterings :
        print(lettering)
```

which results in the same problem.

Using textract, the first half is an empty string:

```py
import textract

text = textract.process(pdfpath)
print(text.decode('utf-8'))
```

Same thing with PyPDF2:

```py
import PyPDF2


pdfFileObj = open(pdfpath, 'rb')

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
for index in range(0, pdfReader.numPages) :
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(index)
    print(pageObj.extractText())
```

I don't understand the problem as it's looking like a normal PDF document with normal text. Also some of the PDF documents don't have this problem.

Comment: can you include the link to a sample pdf.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to due to data protection guidelines, but the first half contains text in table format, the second half images with descriptions